# Firestore does not delete document

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a pretty simple structure

```
Surveys (Collection)
|- survey (Document)
```

I just try to delete it as all examples and questions I've found here suppose:

```
deleteSurvey: (survey: Survey, user: firebase.User) => {
    logging.dev('Delete survey for: ' + survey.owner);
    const documentReference = firebase.firestore().collection('Surveys').doc(survey.id);

    if (survey.owner === user.uid) {
        documentReference
            .delete()
            .then(() => {
                logging.dev('Survey for ' + user.uid + ' has been deleted!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                logging.dev(error);
            });
    }
},
```

The exact same query works with `.get()` and survey.id is the document uid.

I've even reduced my rules (just for testing)

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /Surveys/{survey} {
    allow read, write;
  }
}
```

... but no error is thrown and yes, the document does exist and there is no sub-collection, just fields. I can still fetch it and its not written in italic. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

[image: survey with fields]

Comment: Thanks, but no, it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what the delete function is returning with something like

```
deleteSurvey: async (survey: Survey, user: firebase.User) => {
    logging.dev('Delete survey for: ' + survey.owner);
    const documentReference = firebase.firestore().collection('Surveys').doc(survey.id);

    if (survey.owner === user.uid) {
        return await documentReference
            .delete()
            .then((res) => {
                logging.dev(res);
                logging.dev('Survey for ' + user.uid + ' has been deleted!');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                logging.dev(error);
            });
    }
},
```

You can also do both in one operation rather than storing the reference in a constant like:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Surveys')
    .doc(survey.id)
    .delete()
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
    })
```

Comment: I need the reference, because there are different usecases, how and what I want to delete. The delete function from firestore returns nothing, so I dont think thats going to help me here. My main problem is, that nothing is deleted, not that I want to know what. Maybe the return statement was misleading, Ive removed it. ty :)

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot - the code works like a charm, I somehow managed to pass a cached object, which has no id, into this function. Still I would expect the API reject a delete request with no identifier. But I found my error, thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Ehh it happens to all of us! Glad you got it fixed :)